# Working with .restext files programmatically

Tags: .net, localization

We like the [`.restext` file format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216.aspx) (a plain-text alternative to `.resx`) but we need to load these files into our WinForms app programmatically (at run-time). It seems that the only supposed way to work with `.restext` files is to compile them into `.resources` file and then compile them into a DLL that the app code works with.

Is there a way to somehow amend / replace ResourceManager or something like that to read the localization strings directly from the text format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about WinForms, but for ASP.NET you can add a custom resource provider.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14190/ASP-NET-2-0-Custom-SQL-Server-ResourceProvider

Don't see why this should not work for WinForm.